# how to call a jquery function within another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

i have this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('.infinite-container').waypoint('infinite', {
            container: 'auto',
            items: '.infinite-item',
            more: '.infinite-more-link',
            offset: 'bottom-in-view',
            loadingClass: 'infinite-loading',
            onBeforePageLoad: $.noop,
            onAfterPageLoad: $.noop
        });

</script>
```

and i want to call some other functions, for example i want to call this:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.container').stickem();
        });
    </script>
```

and in order to call it i want to replace $.noop on the onAfterPageLoad event

would it look something like this?:

```
 onAfterPageLoad: $.stickem()
```

super new to javascript/jquery if you cant tell.

Comment: Remove the braces  `onAfterPageLoad: $.stickem`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap your code inside a function, which the plugin will call when the `onAfterPageLoad` event fires:

```
onAfterPageLoad: function() {
    $('.container').stickem();
}
```

Comment: that did it, thank you. another question though, would i be able to add more to that paticular function.

Comment: Of course. `=]` Anything inside the function callback will execute once the `onAfterPageLoad` event fires.

Comment: like for example something like this: `onAfterPageLoad: function() {
    $('.container').stickem();
    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
} `

Comment: @user2360599 That will append a twitter script in the page after the `onAfterPageLoad` has fired. I'm not sure whether it is best practice but it should work just fine as long as there are no syntax errors.

Comment: thank you, just tried it but got no luck. but thanks for your help!

Comment: well, those scripts are usually placed directly on the page body, however you're using the async version of the script so it should work nevertheless of where it is placed, seems like it should work. If anything make another question, I'll experiment with the twitter script then.

Comment: @user2360599 Oh, when I copy and paste the code that you posted above there are some 0-width/hidden chars in it causing syntax errors. Try copying from the official twitter page again. `=]` https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button then it works http://jsfiddle.net/Rkbn3/

Comment: just tried again but no luck. I have facebook code as well but that doesnt work either. might just have to change the type of buttons im using

Answer (score 5):

You have to create a function and put your code inside that function. See below for an example:

```
function stickem(){
// your code goes here
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
onAfterPageLoad: stickem;
```

Comment: That will call the function immediately and not pass a reference to the function.  Remove the `()`.